# Assets from module not appearing in pub/static folder

Tags: magento2, module, frontend

Running Magento 2.1

I am building a module with `alert.js` in the `/view/frontend/web/` folder in my module: https://github.com/waynhall/frontend1/tree/master/Pulsestorm/FrontendTutorial1

However, after enabling the module and running `magento setup:upgrade` and `magento setup:di:compile` and reloading the homepage to generate the `pub/static` folder, there is no folder here as I would expect:

> /var/www/magento.dev/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Pulsestorm_FrontendTutorial1/ in order to serve the alert.js

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I meant hello.js, not alert.js.

Comment: Did you try to run static content deploy command?

Comment: Thanks Khoa,

sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Now it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command to generate `pub/static` directory

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

in case if u have enabled opcache in your php.ini u will not see immediately the result. Also the images from the module are not added into pub/static folder. therefore to clear opcache do:

`systemctl restart php<<version.minor>>-fpm` i.e. `systemctl restart php7.4-fpm`